# Why is exocrinous pancreatic cancer so lethal when compared to others?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

I know it seems far fetched, but I would really like to understand why an interference with the regulation of production of pancreatic exocrine products (and which are they) is so [lethal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancreatic_cancer). I know that people having it generally live for one year or less (top is *circa* 5 years).

Why?

Comment: Sure. Go to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancreatic_cancer] and in the vastness there's the info.

Comment: I added it in the question. +1

Comment: One of the (but not the only) reasons for the high mortality rate of pancreatic cancer is the fact that it is *so* difficult to screen for. The symptoms (if any) are most often dismissed as general back or gut pain, and it can take quite a bit of testing before the true cause is found, by which time the cancer has already become metastatic. Unlike the digestive system, there is no good non-invasive way to image the pancreas (such as with a colonoscopy for colon/rectal cancer) except using radiological methods such as X-rays, so there is no safe way to provide for standard screenings.